# How to synchronize user's data with users stored by keycloak in a Jhipster-App?

Tags: keycloak, jhipster

I wanted to create an webapp using JHipster with Keycloak and ran into a problem:
There is no deal to create new users using Keycloak or connecting user specific data to these users.
But if I want to delete a user I have to do that via Keycloak too, so the entry in JHipsters JHI_USER, the role-assignments and all the data created by this user will not be affected from these deletion.
So what I can do to make it possible to delete these user's data as well?

Answer (score 0):

If Keycloak supported SCIM, you could use Apache SCIMple to sync your users. Here's a demo script that shows how to do it with Okta:

https://github.com/mraible/okta-scim-spring-boot-example/blob/main/demo.adoc

Comment: Unfortunally not out of the Box, there exists a plugin that extends keycloak with SCIM, but with all extensions comes new problems and I wanted to keep is as simple as possible, to avoid new Problems. The best solution I found so far is to extend Keycloak with an spi to notify an Spring Boot app, that a User is deleted and perform further actions, but this solution is also a kind of clumsy for enterprise usage.

Comment: There's an open issue to add SCIM to Keycloak: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-2537

I'm not sure how difficult this would be, but I'd be interested in helping make it work!